# Mxgraph getPrettyXml not get custom element value

Tags: javascript, html, mxgraph

It appears that mxgraph getPrettyXml() doesn't get Custom element value. I have a customized template like below.

```
<add as="symbol">
<Symbol label="Symbol" description="" href="" data="{[hi :bill]}">
            <detail>
            <to name="Bill"/>
            <content >
            test
            </content>
            </detail>
            <mxCell vertex="1" 
style="symbol;image=images/symbols/event.png">
                <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="32" height="32" />
            </mxCell>
        </Symbol>
</add>
```

The element content has a value of "test". It is not being picked up by getPrettyXml. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: Submit a PR for adds support for custom elements to the function, https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/src/js/util/mxUtils.js#L670.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out all I need to do is to use getXmL() instead getPrettyXml(); getPrettyXml(); ignores value within the tags.